# Image modification

Tags: images, css, javascript, clone-site

I am a beginner at CSS. I have followed Airbnb clone challenge. I believe that I follow everything the instructor does.
Here is my problem. I added an image from my wix website. And, I added layout, objectift and objectposition according to the instructor.
[image]

When  is written, the image has to change its shape and size. But, nothing happen.
Can you please help me what is problem?

Comment: Welcome, this is a WordPress stack, but I'm not seeing anything WordPress related in your question, is this a WordPress question or is something missing? Generic JS questions go on stackoverflow

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.